# ¿Por qué no puedo subir mí proyecto a Github desde Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, git, github

Ya he trabajado en Github y lo he hecho sin problemas, subía mis proyectos y todo bien. Sin embargo, hace poco volví a entrar y cambié la contraseña, a partir de ahí, ya no me deja subir mis proyectos desde Netbeans, a pesar de que al momento de intentar subirlos, sí cambio la contraseña a la que es actualmente. ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?
El error que me aparece es que no hay autorización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más probable es que se deba [al cambio que tuvo gitHub](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) respecto a sus políticas de seguridad dejando obsoleta la autentificación básica.

Afortunadamente la gente de netbeans lo tiene cubierto, en github debes de generar tu tóken, y en la sección de credenciales usarás tu usuario normal y la contraseña será la clave privada de tu tóken previamente generado.

Hace tiempo les levanté el issue al enterarme del cambio de política de github y [esa fue su respuesta](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5619).

Comment: Efectivamente, generé mi tóken y lo ingresé como contraseña y todo sin problemas, ya pude subir mí proyecto. 

Muchas gracias.